# Django admin inline duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: python, django

Python 3.6 Django 2.0

I have two models:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Domain(models.Model):
    tool_result = GenericRelation('projects.ToolResult')


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ToolResult(models.Model):
    tool = models.ForeignKey('projects.Tool', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id', 'tool')
```

Then in admin class I create generic tabular inline:

```
class ToolResultGenericTabularInline(GenericTabularInline):
    model = ToolResult
    extra = 0

@admin.register(Domain)
class DomainAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ToolResultGenericTabularInline, ]
```

And when I try to save same objects via inline, I get an error:

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "projects_toolresult_content_type_id_object_i_71ee2c2e_uniq" DETAIL: 
>   Key (content_type_id, object_id, tool_id)=(18, 22, 3) already exists.

Is this a django bug ?

Comment: Did you try with a fresh database?

Comment: Yes, when I created objects not via inline, it works fine

Answer (score -1):

Check [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12028)

Django ticket #12028

Comment: but it says it closed

Answer (score -1):

In your meta description of the ToolResult class:

```
class Meta:
        unique_together = ('content_type', 'object_id', 'tool')
```

the unique together line says every tool should be unique within ToolResults. if you remove this unique_together constraint you will be able to save same objects. 
I hope that this helps.

Comment: But I need to have only one Tool result per Tool with 'content_type', 'object_id'

Comment: For example I can't have duplicates if I have:
tool = google
content_type='Domain'
object='1'

Comment: I see it really could be a django related issue then as Jibin suggested: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13091